# If I keep an objects of InputStream into the memory then does it mean I am storing the whole file into the memory?

Tags: java, file, inputstream, heap-memory

I have a class `Sample` which has two constructor. One takes an object of `File` whereas another takes an `InputStream`.

```
package org.xyz.core;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.InputStream;

    /**
     * Created by Ashish Pancholi on 26-03-2016.
     */
    public class Sample {

        File file;

        public Sample(File file){
            this.file=file;
        }

        public Sample(InputStream inputStream){
            this.file = createFileFromInputStream(inputStream);
        }
    }
```

And I am using `LinkedBlockingQueue` that consumes an object of Sample and has depth of 10000;

```
BlockingQueue<String> queue   = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Sample>(10000);
```

Let's assume two cases here:

**Case A:** I initialize so many instances of `Sample` class by passing `InputStream` as an arguments and I pushed all these objects into the `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

**Case B:** I initialize so many instances of `Sample` class by passing `File` object as an arguments and I pushed all these objects into the `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

**In which case my program will take more memory? If I keep an objects of InputStream into the memory then does it mean I am storing the whole file into the memory? What if I have so many large files?**

Updated:

**Please Note: I am creating the `InputStream` by this way:**

```
InputStream is = new TarArchiveInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))));
```

Comment: @AshishPancholi Which subclass of `Inputstream` are you referring to?

Comment: It is unwise to store `InputStream` as a field; who is responsible for closing them? How can you guarantee they'll stay open? But unless you're reading files into a `ByteArrayInputStream` then memory is not a concern.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu any of them, surely. Isn't that the point of abstraction?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes, tt could be any of the subclass of the InputStream. I am trying to see whether the OP is using a buffered stream or non-buffered.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu the point is that whatever argument you put forward must hold for **all** subclasses. It might be buffered, it might be unbuffered, it might be attached to a socket. If the type is a raw `InputStream` then you cannot make any assumptions. What the OP currently happens to be assigning to the `InputSteam` is neither here nor there, as it might change.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu I am creating the `InputStream` by this way: `InputStream is = new TarArchiveInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

An `InputStream` can be buffered or non-buffered, it could store the entire file internally or nothing, it's free to do all of that. There may even be native resources associated with them.

There is a more fundamental problem with this pattern though: `InputStream`s only really make sense as part of a process that reads them. Storing them en masse is a bad idea because:

1. They aren't thread-safe. (Multiple threads reading from an `InputStream` will almost always end in tears.)
2. If we're talking about `FileInputStream`s, they will keep the file open and you may run out of file descriptors.

Comment: Exactly, storing `InputStream` as a field is a Bad Idea TM for any number of reasons. Memory is probably a passing concern.

Comment: I have updated my question and try to understand that `InputStream` which I am using is buffered or non-buffered? It comes by this way:   `InputStream is = new TarArchiveInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))));`

Comment: @AshishPancholi this answer still holds - don't store `InputStream` as a field.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Okay. Thanks. I just curious to know more about `TarArchiveInputStream`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235621/is-tararchiveinputstream-buffered-or-unbuffered-inputstream